# Angular8 Object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code where I am trying to open a dialog box with all my form errors. The issue I am having is that the object "dialogData" errors saying: "ERROR TypeError: dialogData is undefined". I am not sure why. I have tried to declare it as an empty array and that did not work as well.

Like this: "let dialogData: DialogData;"
AND like this: "let dialogData: DialogData = <DialogData>{};"

```
  // get all error messages
  getFormValidationErrors() {
    Object.keys(this.quoteForm.controls).forEach(key => {
      const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = this.quoteForm.get(key).errors;
      let dialogData: DialogData;

      if (controlErrors != null) {
        Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
          console.log('Key control: ' + key + ', keyError: ' + keyError + ', err value: ', controlErrors[keyError]);
          let errorData: ErrorData = { 
            key: key,
            keyError: keyError,
            controlErrors: controlErrors[keyError]
          }
          dialogData.errors.push(errorData);
        });
        this.openDialog(dialogData);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  errors: ErrorData[];
}

export interface ErrorData {
    key: string;
    keyError: string;
    controlErrors: ValidationErrors;
  }

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-validation-errors',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-validation-errors.html',
})
export class DialogValidationErrors {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogValidationErrors>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: How's that DialogData object defined? I mean, is it a custom class you created? Could you please show the structure of it?

Comment: @AnthonySerranoBianco I have added that code snippet. Thank you for looking into this. I know it is probably something stupid I just cannot see it lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are small things I would actually change.

Initially, your DialogData interface could be a concrete class, so you could easily instance it. Also, you never create an instance of your ErrorData array, so when trying to push something it will most likely fail.

So these are the changes I'd do.

**In your dialog-validation-errors component:** Change your DialogData interface to below

```
export class DialogData {
  errors = new Array<ErrorData>(); // Here you make sure there's always an instance of the array.
}
```

**In your getFormValidationErrors method:** Create an instance of the DialogData class as a const

```
// get all error messages
getFormValidationErrors() {
    Object.keys(this.quoteForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = this.quoteForm.get(key).errors;
        
        // Change 1 - This creates your errors array instance as well
        // as we have the inline initialization in your DialogData class
        const dialogData = new DialogData();

        if (controlErrors != null) {
            Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
                console.log('Key control: ' + key + ', keyError: ' + keyError + ', err value: ', controlErrors[keyError]);
                let errorData: ErrorData = { 
                    key: key,
                    keyError: keyError,
                    controlErrors: controlErrors[keyError]
                }

              dialogData.errors.push(errorData);
            });
         }
    });

    // Change 2 - You probably don't want to open the dialog n times in your foreach loop.
    // Maybe it's better to do it after all the dialog data is calculated?
    this.openDialog(dialogData);
}
```

I made a quick test here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-cqdwnj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you've declared `DialogData` as an interface and not a class.
And you declared a variable of type `DialogData`, and you are trying to access `dialogData.errors` without instantating the `dialogData`, hence its complaining that *dialogData is undefined*.

```
// get all error messages
getFormValidationErrors() {
    Object.keys(this.quoteForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        const controlErrors: ValidationErrors =     this.quoteForm.get(key).errors;
        let dialogData: DialogData; //<-- DialogData is not initialized

        if (controlErrors != null) {
            Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
            console.log('Key control: ' + key + ', keyError: ' + keyError + ', err value: ', controlErrors[keyError]);
                let errorData: ErrorData = { 
                    key: key,
                    keyError: keyError,
                    controlErrors: controlErrors[keyError]
                }
                dialogData.errors.push(errorData); //<-- trying to access dialogData.errors
            });
            this.openDialog(dialogData);
        }
    });
}
```

a simple fix would be to replace that line with

```
let dialogData: DialogData = {errors: []};
```

or change `DialogData` to class and instantiate the object

```
let dialogData: DialogData = new DialogData();
```